# Simple tailwind dropdown

Tags: jquery, css, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I'm trying to create a simple navbar with dropdown using tailwind framework.

Here is my snippet:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2.x.x/dist/alpine.min.js" defer=""></script>
<nav class="bg-gray-800 fixed w-full z-10 top-0">
   <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-2 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
      <div class="relative flex items-center justify-between h-16">
         <div class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center sm:hidden">
            <!-- Mobile menu button-->
            <button type="button" class="inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-white" aria-controls="mobile-menu" aria-expanded="false">
               <span class="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
               <!-- Icon when menu is closed. -->
               <!--
                  Heroicon name: outline/menu
                  
                  Menu open: "hidden", Menu closed: "block"
                  -->
               <svg class="block h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"></path>
               </svg>
               <!-- Icon when menu is open. -->
               <!--
                  Heroicon name: outline/x
                  
                  Menu open: "block", Menu closed: "hidden"
                  -->
               <svg class="hidden h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                  <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"></path>
               </svg>
            </button>
         </div>
         <div class="flex-1 flex items-center justify-center sm:items-stretch sm:justify-start">
            <div class="flex-shrink-0 flex items-center">
               <img class="block lg:hidden h-8 w-auto" src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-mark-indigo-500.svg" alt="Workflow">
               <img class="hidden lg:block h-8 w-auto" src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-logo-indigo-500-mark-white-text.svg" alt="Workflow">
            </div>
            <div class="hidden sm:block mx-auto">
               <div class="flex space-x-4">
                  <!-- Current: "bg-gray-900 text-white", Default: "text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white" -->
                  <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">Menu 1</a>
                  <a href="#" class="bg-gray-900 text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">Menu 2</a>
                  <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">Menu 3</a>
                  <a href="#" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">Menu 4</a>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 sm:static sm:inset-auto sm:ml-6 sm:pr-0">
            <!-- Notifications dropdown -->
            <div class="ml-3 relative">
               <div x-data="{ dropdownOpen: false }" class="relative my-32">
                  <button @click="dropdownOpen = !dropdownOpen" class="relative z-10 block rounded-md bg-white p-2 focus:outline-none">
                     <svg class="h-5 w-5 text-gray-800" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                        <path d="M10 2a6 6 0 00-6 6v3.586l-.707.707A1 1 0 004 14h12a1 1 0 00.707-1.707L16 11.586V8a6 6 0 00-6-6zM10 18a3 3 0 01-3-3h6a3 3 0 01-3 3z"></path>
                     </svg>
                  </button>
                  <div x-show="dropdownOpen" @click="dropdownOpen = false" class="fixed inset-0 h-full w-full z-10" style="display: none;"></div>
                  <div x-show="dropdownOpen" class="absolute right-0 mt-2 bg-white rounded-md shadow-lg overflow-hidden z-20" style="width: 20rem; display: none;">
                     <div class="py-2">
                        <a href="#" class="flex items-center px-4 py-3 border-b hover:bg-gray-100 -mx-2">
                           <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full object-cover mx-1" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494790108377-be9c29b29330?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=334&amp;q=80" alt="avatar">
                           <p class="text-gray-600 text-sm mx-2">
                              <span class="font-bold" href="#">Sara Salah</span> replied on the <span class="font-bold text-blue-500" href="#">Upload Image</span> artical . 2m
                           </p>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="flex items-center px-4 py-3 border-b hover:bg-gray-100 -mx-2">
                           <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full object-cover mx-1" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531427186611-ecfd6d936c79?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=634&amp;q=80" alt="avatar">
                           <p class="text-gray-600 text-sm mx-2">
                              <span class="font-bold" href="#">Slick Net</span> start following you . 45m
                           </p>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="flex items-center px-4 py-3 border-b hover:bg-gray-100 -mx-2">
                           <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full object-cover mx-1" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1450297350677-623de575f31c?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=334&amp;q=80" alt="avatar">
                           <p class="text-gray-600 text-sm mx-2">
                              <span class="font-bold" href="#">Jane Doe</span> Like Your reply on <span class="font-bold text-blue-500" href="#">Test with TDD</span> artical . 1h
                           </p>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="flex items-center px-4 py-3 hover:bg-gray-100 -mx-2">
                           <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full object-cover mx-1" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1580489944761-15a19d654956?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=398&amp;q=80" alt="avatar">
                           <p class="text-gray-600 text-sm mx-2">
                              <span class="font-bold" href="#">Abigail Bennett</span> start following you . 3h
                           </p>
                        </a>
                     </div>
                     <a href="#" class="block bg-gray-800 text-white text-center font-bold py-2">Marquer comme lu</a>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ml-3 relative">
               <div x-data="{ dropdownOpen: false }" class="relative my-32">
                  <button @click="dropdownOpen = !dropdownOpen" class="relative z-10 block rounded-md p-2 focus:outline-none">
                  <span class="sr-only">Open user menu</span>
                  <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full" src="img/profile_user.svg" alt="">
                  </button>
                  <div x-show="dropdownOpen" @click="dropdownOpen = false" class="fixed inset-0 h-full w-full z-10" style="display: none;"></div>
                  <div x-show="dropdownOpen" class="absolute w-64 right-0 mt-2 bg-white rounded-md shadow-lg overflow-hidden z-20" style="display: none;">
                     <div class="py-2">
                        <a href="#" class="flex block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100" role="menuitem"><img class="mr-5" src="icons/outline/users.svg">Link 1</a>
                        <a href="#" class="flex block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100" role="menuitem"><img class="mr-5" src="icons/outline/user.svg">Link 2</a>
                        <a href="#" class="flex block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100" role="menuitem"><img class="mr-5" src="icons/outline/adjustments.svg">Link 3</a>
                        <a href="#" class="flex block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100" role="menuitem"><img class="mr-5" src="icons/outline/lightning-bolt.svg">Link 4</a>
                        <a href="#" class="flex block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100" role="menuitem"><img class="mr-5" src="icons/outline/support.svg">Link 5</a>
                        <a href="#" class="flex block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100" role="menuitem"><img class="mr-5" src="icons/outline/logout.svg">Link 6</a>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <!-- Mobile menu, show/hide based on menu state. -->
   <div class="sm:hidden" id="mobile-menu">
      <div class="px-2 pt-2 pb-3 space-y-1">
         <!-- Current: "bg-gray-900 text-white", Default: "text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white" -->
         <a href="/recettes" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Recettes</a>
         <a href="/planning" class="bg-gray-900 text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Planning</a>
         <a href="/courses" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Courses</a>
         <a href="/mensuration" class="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium">Mensuration</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

How can I make it work gracefully using jQuery or/and Alpine ? (I'd like to have both solutions)

An issue I'm facing, in the snippet it's possible to open both dropdown

Answer (score 0):

### Check the snippet that I made to work for me.

---

```js
document.getElementById('togglemebutton').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("resultnav").classList.toggle("hidden");
}

//document.getElementById('togglemebutton').onclick = function () {
//  document.getElementById("toggleme").classList.toggle("hidden");
//}


const toggleprofile = document.getElementById("toggleprofile");
const resultprofile = document.getElementById("resultprofile");
[...document.querySelectorAll('body')].forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', event => {
    if (event.target.parentElement.id !== "toggleprofile") {
      console.clear();
      console.log(event.target.parentElement.id)
      resultprofile.classList.add("hidden")
    }else{
    resultprofile.classList.toggle("hidden")}
  })
})
```

```css
body{
height:350px}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<nav class="bg-gray-800">
  <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-2 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
    <div class="relative flex items-center justify-between h-16">
      <div class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center sm:hidden">
        <!-- Mobile menu button-->
        <button id="togglemebutton" class="inline-flex items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-700 focus:text-white transition duration-150 ease-in-out" aria-label="Main menu"
          aria-expanded="false">
          <!-- Icon when menu is closed. -->
          <!-- Menu open: "hidden", Menu closed: "block" -->
          <svg class="block h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
          </svg>
          <!-- Icon when menu is open. -->
          <!-- Menu open: "block", Menu closed: "hidden" -->
          <svg class="hidden h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-1 flex items-center justify-center sm:items-stretch sm:justify-start">
        <div class="flex-shrink-0">
          <img class="block lg:hidden h-8 w-auto" src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-mark-on-dark.svg" alt="Workflow logo">
          <img class="hidden lg:block h-8 w-auto" src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-mark-on-dark.svg" alt="Workflow logo">
        </div>
        <div class="hidden sm:block sm:ml-6">
          <div class="flex">
            <a href="#" class="px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-white bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Dashboard</a>
            <a href="#" class="ml-4 px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Team</a>
            <a href="#" class="ml-4 px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Projects</a>
            <a href="#" class="ml-4 px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Calendar</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 sm:static sm:inset-auto sm:ml-6 sm:pr-0">
        <button class="p-1 border-2 border-transparent text-gray-400 rounded-full hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out" aria-label="Notifications">
          <svg class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15 17h5l-1.405-1.405A2.032 2.032 0 0118 14.158V11a6.002 6.002 0 00-4-5.659V5a2 2 0 10-4 0v.341C7.67 6.165 6 8.388 6 11v3.159c0 .538-.214 1.055-.595 1.436L4 17h5m6 0v1a3 3 0 11-6 0v-1m6 0H9" />
          </svg>
        </button>

        <!-- Profile dropdown -->
        <div class="ml-3 relative">
          <div>
            <button id="toggleprofile" class="flex text-sm border-2 border-transparent rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:border-white transition duration-150 ease-in-out" id="user-menu" aria-label="User menu" aria-haspopup="true">
              <img class="h-8 w-8 rounded-full" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1472099645785-5658abf4ff4e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=facearea&facepad=2&w=256&h=256&q=80" alt="">
            </button>
          </div>
          <!--
            Profile dropdown panel, show/hide based on dropdown state.

            Entering: "transition ease-out duration-100"
              From: "transform opacity-0 scale-95"
              To: "transform opacity-100 scale-100"
            Leaving: "transition ease-in duration-75"
              From: "transform opacity-100 scale-100"
              To: "transform opacity-0 scale-95"
          -->
          <div id="resultprofile" class="hidden z-40 origin-top-right absolute right-0 mt-2 w-48 rounded-md shadow-lg">
            <div class="py-1 rounded-md bg-white shadow-xs" role="menu" aria-orientation="vertical" aria-labelledby="user-menu">
              <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 transition duration-150 ease-in-out" role="menuitem">Your Profile</a>
              <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 transition duration-150 ease-in-out" role="menuitem">Settings</a>
              <a href="#" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 transition duration-150 ease-in-out" role="menuitem">Sign out</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!--
    Mobile menu, toggle classes based on menu state.

    Menu open: "block", Menu closed: "hidden"
  -->
  <div id="resultnav" class="hidden sm:hidden">
    <div class="px-2 pt-2 pb-3">
      <a href="#" class="block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-white bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Dashboard</a>
      <a href="#" class="mt-1 block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Team</a>
      <a href="#" class="mt-1 block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Projects</a>
      <a href="#" class="mt-1 block px-3 py-2 rounded-md text-base font-medium text-gray-300 hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700 focus:outline-none focus:text-white focus:bg-gray-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out">Calendar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**Use script tag inside HTML or outside.
You needed to just use event listener on all elements in the javascript.**

**Remember:** There's no need to add CSS which I used body{...} as it is just to change element's height inside the post.